# How to set PHP syntax highlighting in GVIM on Windows?

Tags: windows, gvim, syntax-highlighting

My GVIM 7.3.46 install on Windows XP Professional SP3 32bit does not seem to have PHP syntax highlighting. I have added [this file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571) to `C:\Documents and Settings\myUsername\vimfiles\syntax` and set this in VIM:

```
au! Syntax php source C:\Documents and Settings\dotancohen\vimfiles\syntax\vim.php
```

However, running `set syntax=php` does not highlight files as PHP, neither for files with the .php extension nor for no-extension files.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GVim should have PHP syntax enabled by default.

1) Check for the existance of the file:

```
C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\syntax\php.vim
```

2)

```
C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim
```

should include the line:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.php,*.php\d,*.phtml,*.ctp       setf php
```

It sounds like you might want to try uninstalling GVim and reinstalling it again.

Comment: Thank you jfuga, both the conditions that you mention are true. What else might cause GVIM to refuse to syntax-highlight PHP files?

Comment: Do you have a _vimrc file?  If so, make sure "syntax on" is listed as a command within this file.

Comment: Thanks, I do have that file. In fact, I just found out that [removing _vimrc enables syntax highlighting](http://superuser.com/questions/413478/no-syntax-highlighting-in-gvim-on-windows-with-vimrc)!