# No syntax highlighting in GVIM on Windows with _vimrc

Tags: windows, gvim, syntax-highlighting

My GVIM 7.3.46 install on Windows XP Professional SP3 32bit does not perform syntax highlighting if there exists a `_vimrc` file, at least not PHP and C. Even explicitly mentioning `set syntax=php` I get not highlighting, whether or not the filename extension ends in `.php`.

Even if there is a 0-byte blank file in `C:\Documents and Settings\myUsername\_vimrc` then files will not be syntax highlighted. I can rename that 0-byte file to `_vimrcBLAH` and syntax highlighting works again.

What might cause this, and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The gvim program alone does not have syntax highlighting enabled by default. Syntax highlighting is only enabled by explicitly enabling it with a command such as `:syntax on`. So the only way to have syntax enabled is to enable it yourself at the Vim command line or to have such a command in a configuration file that's read on startup.

Vim is typically installed on Windows with a standard set of configuration commands in `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc`. That standard set includes `syntax on`. Without any other configuration files, gvim will read that file on startup and you will have syntax highlighting.

In `:help _vimrc` it says, "Four places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists is used, the others are ignored." The list of user vimrc files includes `$HOME/_vimrc` followed by `$VIM/_vimrc`. On your system, $VIM is `C:\Program Files\Vim`.

So, when you use a `C:\Documents and Settings\myUsername\_vimrc` file, gvim reads that file and skips `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc`. If your _vimrc does not contain `syntax on` you will not get syntax highlighting.

If your are going to use your own _vimrc, then make sure you copy into it from `C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc` any of those configuration commands you need, including `syntax on`.

Comment: Thank you Gary! This is _exactly_ what I needed to know. I'm rather glad to know that the answer is in the fine manual, I'm going to go through it later today. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that. How odd that `gvim` 7.3 on Linux seems to default this to `on` (I can't find `syntax on` in any of the `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc` files on my Linux system), but `gvim` 7.3 on Windows doesn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The set of files discussed in the answer are referred to as *personal* initialization files. Before loading one of those, Vim searches for and loads a *system* initialization file. (See `:help startup`.) A standard Vim installation on Windows has a *personal* initialization file at $VIM/_vimrc but no *system* initialization file, so your $HOME/_vimrc is loaded *instead of* $VIM/_vimrc. A standard Vim installation on a Linux distribution has a *system* initialization file usually at $VIM/vimrc which is always loaded before and *in addition to* the *personal* initialization file.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: So you will find a `syntax on` command in the *system* initialization file on your Linux system, probably in /usr/share/vim/vimrc or /etc/vimrc. The location is given in the output of the `:version` command.

Comment: @garyjohn: Right, I looked in those as well before posting the above. I can't find one in any of them. I've looked in any `.vimrc`, `.gvimrc`, and `gvimrc` file I could find under both `$VIM` and `$HOME`.

Comment: @garyjohn: The one I missed out was `$VIM/vimrc` (no `.`). That's where it was hiding. I looked for `$VIM/.vimrc` instead (doh!). We should clean these comments up, they won't help anyone who doesn't do the same dumb thing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $HOME/_vimrc will be picked up first if it exists, and I don't like to change the stock config file, I just add this line in my $HOME/_vimrc. This way I get my setting done in $HOME/_vimrc, and pick up all the other setting from the installations. And it works even after any reinstall or upgrade.

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/../_vimrc
```

Comment: How exactly is your answer related to a question tagged **windows**?

Comment: I am not familiar with the software but it might refer to a configuration file? Perhaps the author can clarify?

Comment: Okay, my use of $HOME might be questionable but I was talking about windows. On Windows 7 it should be C:\Users\<ID>. The _vimrc under that directory will always be picked up first.